# Copy Multiple Files and report progress C#

Tags: c#

After looking at multiple questions/answers I couldn't find a solution for my problem. I remember I got this code from some question here at StackOverflow and it works perfectly but just for one file. What I want is multiple files.

This is the original CopyTo Function:

```
    public static void CopyTo(this FileInfo file, FileInfo destination, Action<int> progressCallback)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;  //1MB
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize], buffer2 = new byte[bufferSize];
        bool swap = false;
        int progress = 0, reportedProgress = 0, read = 0;

        long len = file.Length;
        float flen = len;
        Task writer = null;

        using (var source = file.OpenRead())
        using (var dest = destination.OpenWrite())
        {
            //dest.SetLength(source.Length);
            for (long size = 0; size < len; size += read)
            {
                if ((progress = ((int)((size / flen) * 100))) != reportedProgress)
                    progressCallback(reportedProgress = progress);
                read = source.Read(swap ? buffer : buffer2, 0, bufferSize);
                writer?.Wait();  // if < .NET4 // if (writer != null) writer.Wait(); 
                writer = dest.WriteAsync(swap ? buffer : buffer2, 0, read);
                swap = !swap;
            }
            writer?.Wait();  //Fixed - Thanks @sam-hocevar
        }
    }
```

So here is how I start the file copy process:

```
                var ficheiro = ficheirosCopia.ElementAt(x);
                var _source = new FileInfo(ficheiro.Key);
                var _destination = new FileInfo(ficheiro.Value);

                if (_destination.Exists)
                {
                    _destination.Delete();
                }

                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    _source.CopyTo(_destination, perc => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressBar.SetProgress(perc)));
                }).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => MessageBox.Show("File Copied!"));
```

This works very well when I copy only one file but I need to copy multiple files. So I've started to change things a bit:

```
    public static void CopyTo(Dictionary<string, string> files, Action<int> progressCallback)
    {
        int globalProgress = 0, globalReportedProgress = 0, globalRead = 0;

        for (var x = 0; x < files.Count; x++)
        {
            var item = files.ElementAt(x);
            var file = new FileInfo(item.Key);
            var destination = new FileInfo(item.Value);

            const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;  //1MB
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize], buffer2 = new byte[bufferSize];
            bool swap = false;
            int progress = 0, reportedProgress = 0, read = 0;

            long len = file.Length;
            float flen = len;
            Task writer = null;

            using (var source = file.OpenRead())
            using (var dest = destination.OpenWrite())
            {
                for (long size = 0; size < len; size += read)
                {
                    if ((progress = ((int)((size / flen) * 100))) != reportedProgress)
                        progressCallback(reportedProgress = progress);
                    read = source.Read(swap ? buffer : buffer2, 0, bufferSize);
                    writer?.Wait();  // if < .NET4 // if (writer != null) writer.Wait(); 
                    writer = dest.WriteAsync(swap ? buffer : buffer2, 0, read);
                    swap = !swap;
                }
                writer?.Wait();  //Fixed - Thanks @sam-hocevar
            }
        }

    }
```

Of course this code has a lot of errors but I can't understand how this should be done.

The main goal would be to Start a single task for multiple tiles and having progresscallback for global copy. Receiving a Dictionary (it's already created on other part of the code) as a parameter.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but why do you not use the FileCopy method of the File object? Only for your progressbar?

Comment: What do you mean only for the progress bar? can you ellaborate please?

Comment: I believe he means this: if you dont need to update the progress bar per for example kb copied, you can just use File.Copy() as a solution in a loop.

Comment: Take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). This should help you with your implementation

Comment: Yup but I need. I think the solution is before going for every single file and start copying I need to decalde a global count for all files length and start reporting and receiving for that and not the the single file size.

Comment: @niklas u r right

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two approaches to this, one reporting progress after each file, and the other reporting progress every n bytes.

```
namespace StackOverflow41750117CopyProgress
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;

    public class Batch
    {
        private bool _overwrite;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Batch"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="overwrite">
        /// True to overwrite the destination file if it already exists (default),
        /// false to throw an exception if the destination file already exists.
        /// </param>
        public Batch(bool overwrite = true)
        {
            this._overwrite = overwrite;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Copies the files, reporting progress once per file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filesToCopy">
        /// A dictionary with the paths of the source files as its keys, and the path to the destination file as its values.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="progressCallback">
        /// A callback which accepts two Int64 parameters - the number of bytes copied so far, and the total number of bytes to copy.
        /// </param>
        public void CopyReportingPerFile(Dictionary<string, string> filesToCopy, Action<long, long> progressCallback)
        {
            var bytesToCopy = this.GetTotalFileSize(filesToCopy);
            long totalBytesCopied = 0;
            foreach (var copy in filesToCopy)
            {
                File.Copy(copy.Key, copy.Value, this._overwrite);
                totalBytesCopied += new FileInfo(copy.Key).Length;
                progressCallback(totalBytesCopied, bytesToCopy);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Copies the files, reporting progress once per read/write operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filesToCopy">
        /// A dictionary with the paths of the source files as its keys, and the path to the destination file as its values.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="progressCallback">
        /// A callback which accepts two Int64 parameters - the number of bytes copied so far, and the total number of bytes to copy.
        /// </param>
        public void CopyReportingPerBuffer(Dictionary<string, string> filesToCopy, Action<long, long> progressCalllback)
        {
            var bytesToCopy = this.GetTotalFileSize(filesToCopy);
            var bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50;
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            var span = new Span<byte>(buffer);
            long totalBytesCopied = 0;
            foreach (var copy in filesToCopy)
            {
                using (var source = File.OpenRead(copy.Key))
                using (var destination = File.OpenWrite(copy.Value))
                {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        // The Read method returns 0 once we've reached the end of the file
                        bytesRead = source.Read(span);
                        destination.Write(span);
                        totalBytesCopied += bytesRead;
                        progressCalllback(totalBytesCopied, bytesToCopy);
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);

                    source.Close();
                    destination.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private long GetTotalFileSize(Dictionary<string, string> filesToCopy)
        {
            long bytesToCopy = 0;
            foreach (var filename in filesToCopy.Keys)
            {
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
                bytesToCopy += fileInfo.Length;
            }

            return bytesToCopy;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
namespace StackOverflow41750117CopyProgress
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filesToCopy = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            filesToCopy.Add(@"C:\temp\1.mp4", @"C:\temp\1copy.mp4");
            filesToCopy.Add(@"C:\temp\2.mp4", @"C:\temp\2copy.mp4");
            filesToCopy.Add(@"C:\temp\3.mp4", @"C:\temp\3copy.mp4");
            filesToCopy.Add(@"C:\temp\4.mp4", @"C:\temp\4copy.mp4");
            filesToCopy.Add(@"C:\temp\5.mp4", @"C:\temp\5copy.mp4");
            filesToCopy.Add(@"C:\temp\6.mp4", @"C:\temp\6copy.mp4");
            filesToCopy.Add(@"C:\temp\7.mp4", @"C:\temp\7copy.mp4");

            // Make sure the destination files don't already exist
            foreach (var copy in filesToCopy)
            {
                File.Delete(copy.Value);
            }

            var batch = new Batch();
            Console.WriteLine($"Started  {DateTime.Now}");
            batch.CopyReportingPerFile(filesToCopy, (bytesCopied, bytesToCopy) => Console.WriteLine($"Copied {bytesCopied} bytes of {bytesToCopy}"));
            //batch.CopyReportingPerBuffer(filesToCopy, (bytesCopied, bytesToCopy) => Console.WriteLine($"Copied {bytesCopied} bytes of {bytesToCopy}"));
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

A few observations...

- Reporting progress once per file was easier to implement but doesn't meet the requirements of the question, and isn't very responsive if you're copying a small number of large files.
- Using File.Copy preserves the original file's modified date, reading the files into memory and then writing them does not.
- Increasing the buffer size from 1MB to 10MB and them 50MB increased the memory usage and also improved the performance, although most of that performance improvement seems to be as a result of calling `Console.Writeline` in my `progressCallback` less often, rather than increasing the speed of the disk I/O.
- The optimum balance between performance and frequency of progress reports will depend on your circumstances and the spec of the machine running the process, but I found a 50MB buffer results in a progress report roughly once per second.
- Note the use of `Span<byte>` rather than `byte[]` for the buffer that the data is read into and written from - this removes the need for my code to keep track of the current position in the file (and that's something new I learned today).

I know I'm rather late to this question, but hopefully someone will find this useful.